# facade unit test with jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I don't know how to test this function in my facade:

```
getItem(number: string): Observable<MyItem> {
   return this.myStore.pipe(select(myQuery.getItem(number)));
}
```

I think maybe something like this:

```
it('getItem should return my item', () => {
store = TestBed.inject(Store);
spyOn(store, 'pipe').and.callThrough();
facade.getShoppingCartItem('1');
expect(store).toEqual(getItemsStub());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
it('should get item', (done) => {
    store.overrideSelector(getState, myMock);
    facade.getShoppingCartItem(myMock.shoppingCartItems[0].id).subscribe(item => {
        expect(item).toBeDefined();
        done();
    });
});
```